# "La fabrication et la livraison du produit est/sont considéré(es) comme faisant partie du service offert", accord du participe

Tags: pluriel, accord, participe-passé, passif

Dans cette phrase j'aurais, d’instinct, accordé "considéré" avec "la fabrication et la livraison" donc au féminin pluriel. Je ne vois aucune raison de ne pas le faire, mais comme la phrase originale

> "La fabrication et la livraison du produit **est considéré** comme faisant
>   partie du service offert"

est tirée d'un contrat officiel révisé par des avocats **et** un traducteur professionnel... je me dis que quelque chose doit m'échapper.

J'ai consulté le CNRTL, Collins, Larousse et le Grevisse, mais je n'ai pas trouvé de réponse.

Donc, ici, faut-il écrire "considéré" ou "considérées" ? Si on ne fait pas l'accord, pourquoi ?

Comment: L'erreur parait grossière. La phrase fait-elle partie d'une expression plus grande telle que "Tout ce qui concerne la fabrication [...] est considéré" ?

Comment: @jhyn Non, le texte précédent n'est pas lié grammaticalement parlant: " Le fournisseur s'efforcera d'émettre et d'expédier les nouvelles cartes en temps opportun." Cette phrase est le début de la section entière.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Les deux se disent et les deux se dit.

Mais il faut choisir:

> "La fabrication et la livraison du produit est considérée comme faisant partie du service offert".

soit

> "La fabrication et la livraison du produit sont considérées comme faisant partie du service offert"

au féminin dans les deux cas.

Answer (score 5):

Un sujet double coordonné avec *et*? *Sont considérées* sans hésitations pour moi.

Comment: Je pensais qu'il y avait peut-être une exception liée au verbe ou au domaine du droit du commerce, une sorte de formule archaïque conservées en l'état.